# How to select files in directory that match a specific name filter? -- php

Tags: php

Im trying to build a database update script that execute mysqldumps starting from the next version that the app is actually running. I place these dumps in a folder when there are some changes in the database. The following scrip work do the job, but if i set the filter below the current < version it shows the correct file, if i set the filter to show above (>) the current version it show the right ones PLUS schema_backup.sql and that shouldnt. In my sql folder i have:

- 0.2.0.sql
- 0.2.1.sql
- 0.2.2.sql
- 0.2.3.sql
- schema_backup.sql

Code:

```
$current_version = '0.2.1'; 


$dir = "sql/";

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
    if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..') && ($file > $current_version . '.sql')) {

   echo "" . $file . "<br>";
      exec('mysql -h' . host . ' -u' . username . ' -p' . password . ' ' . database . ' < sql/' . $file . '.sql');

 }
 }
 closedir($dh);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just strip out the wrong files based on the first character of the file name and use [`version_compare()`](http://php.net/version_compare) to perform the comparison:

```
foreach (glob("$dir/[0-9]*.sql") as $file) {
    if (version_compare($current_version, pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME), '<')) {
        // load dump
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, i didnt knew the version compare func, must be intersting to do a mix of both, ill do some test with this method. Thanks.

Comment: I think version_compare just read the number string and ignore if the file have a no number name

Comment: @Aramil Hence the `glob()` statement to make sure a file name starts with a number.

Comment: I thinks using version compare is the right way to go. Using the first method i must have a string like 1.1.1 if i have only two numbers it skip it. Version compare do the job no matter how long is my version number. In the test i did the glob statament seems to dont be necessary it skip anything thats not a regular version string. Both answers are right, Dwayne method work good, but version compare should be the way to go in this case. I should mark this one as the right one?

Answer (score 1):

Add `preg_match('/\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.sql/',$file)` to your if statement. (You can remove the `.` and `..` checks.)

```
if (preg_match('/\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.sql/',$file) && $file > $current_version.'.sql'))
```

The parts of the regular expression are:

```
/ ... /     boundary of the expression

\\d+        one or more digits (backslash must be double so preg "sees" \d

\\.         a literal period (again, double backslash to get one)

sql         the file extension
```

Comment: Nice it work! Thanks, just to be sure to understand it, in each \\d+\\   you are specifying that it should be a digit right?

Comment: Thanks Dwayne, your code work great, but in order to help others looking for the same solution, the version compare seems the right way to go. Thats why i mark the other solution as the right one.